# How to set values to array when async webservice responce is called

Tags: javascript

Friends,

I have declared array in javascipt

```
var Answer1 = new Array(50);
```

I want to call webserivce using $ajax & i want to store its response at appropriate index of array.
& want to use that array immediately after all the values are set.
Currently i am doing this by using `async:false` property of $ajax .
Does anyone know way with asynchrnous way because when i use asynchronous values of array remains undefined.

```
for(var j=0;j < mycollection.length-1;j++)
{
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: webserviceURL,
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(data)
                {
                    //alert(data.error);
                },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    if(data.error!=null)
                    {
                        console.log('data error');
                        Answer1[j] = data.name;
                    }
               },
                complete: function(data)
                {
                alert('completed:');
                },
                data: {},
                async: false
            });
```

Comment: Could you post more code to help us understand what you are trying to do and what is wrong currently?

Comment: @MattFellows Please let me know how to do this with asynchronous call

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using the wrong index for Answer1:

```
Answer1[i] = data.name;
```

should be:

```
Answer1[j] = data.name;
```

But if that still doesn't work, pass j as a parameter to your webservice and get the webservice to return it as part of the response so you know the index to assign to.

Also you are only assigning if data.error is not null?  Is that what you want, didn't you want to assign if there is no error (i.e. data.error is null)?

Answer (score 0):

Put whatever code uses the array into a function. Call that function from the success handler for your Ajax call.